# Uglifying for require.js with shim doesn't work on play2 with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, playframework-2.0, requirejs

I work on Play 2.1.2 project, using Angular.js, CoffeeScript, require.js and bower to organize front-end.
With bower, I use shim in my `/app/assets/javascripts/main.coffee` file.
Then I deploy using `play clean stage` and running `target/start`.

The problem is: during `stage` phase, Play doesn't uglify resources.
In `Build.scala`:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  requireJs += "main",
  requireJsShim += "main.js"
)
```

Then after uglyfying css in stage:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Error: Load timeout for modules: angular-bootstrap,angular
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
In module tree:
    main
      jquery

Error: Load timeout for modules: angular-bootstrap,angular
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
In module tree:
    main
      jquery

[info] RequireJS optimization finished.
```

So nothing was uglified. In `main.coffee`:

```
require.config
  paths:
    jquery: "lib/jquery/jquery"
    angular: "lib/angular/angular"
    ...
  shim:
    angular: {deps: ["jquery"], exports: "angular"}
    ...

define [
  "angular-bootstrap"
  "angular"
  ...
], ->
  app = angular.module "app"
  ...
  app
```

It works perfectly on client side, all paths are correct and so on.
`requireJsShim += "main.js"` also looks correct: it looks like require.js optimization takes place after compiling assets, so `main.coffee` or just `main` doesn't work.

Any ideas what are the roots of the problem? Have anyone faced it before?

Comment: main.coffee is not the target, but main.js (after compilation). Don't you have a main.js somewhere in your target folder (on start command) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [example](https://github.com/jmparsons/play-scala-backbone-todo/pull/1) application using the shim where I just answered a question very similar to yours. In a nutshell, the shim overwrites the [app.build.js](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayCommands.scala) file.

Comment: [info] ({appDir: "javascripts",
[info]           baseUrl: ".",
[info]           dir:"javascripts-min", mainConfigFile: "javascripts/shim.js", modules: [{name: "main"}]})
Error: /var/www/play-scala-backbone-todo/target/scala-2.10/classes/public/javascripts/shim.js does not exist.

Comment: I have cloned your example, but during `play stage` it cannot find `shim.js` -- it was deleted in a recent commit. So require.js optimization fails.

Comment: it works for me only with `paths` in `require.config`, but with no `shim` -- I have to state shim deps explicitly :(

Comment: Yeah I would be weary of treating the Play shim like how the require js docs use shim i.e. including deps and exports. It's more of a require file check lol...to find out what dependency files are necessary for the uglification.

Answer (score 1):

What finally solved my problem is creating custom `shim.coffee` with part of `require.config` in it:

```
require.config
  paths:
    jquery: "lib/jquery/jquery"
    angular: "lib/angular/angular"
    ...
```

Without `shim` part.

Then I had to explicitly define shimmed dependencies in `define` clauses and use `requireJsShim += "shim.js"` -- not the same file that I use for client-side configuration.

Then uglifying and require.js optimization begin to work!

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered exactly this problem (almost; I'm not using CoffeeScript in my project), and it turns out easier to solve that I thought. To restate the issue: certain JavaScript resources—particularly those without an `export` setting in their shim—would produce the “Load timeout for modules” stated above. Worse, the problem appeared to be transient.

Separating the RequireJS configuration (*e.g.*, `paths`, `shim`) from the module seemed to help, but compiling remained unreliable and it made working in development mode more complex.

I found that adding `waitSeconds: 0` to the configuration object contributed to reliable builds. Why timeouts are even possible for accessing local resources during compilation is beyond me. See the [RequireJS API `waitSeconds` documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-waitSeconds) for details.

Here's a snippet from my RequireJS module, located in `public/javascripts` (your paths will likely differ).

```
require({
  /* Fixes an unexplained bug where module loads would timeout
   * at compilation. */
  waitSeconds: 0,

  paths: {
    'angular': '../vendor/angular/angular',
    'angular-animate': '../vendor/angular/angular-animate',
    /* ... */

    'jquery': '../vendor/jquery/jquery'
  },

  shim: {
    'angular': {
      deps: [ 'jquery' ],
      exports: 'angular'
    },

    'angular-animate': ['angular'],
    /* ... */

    'jquery': {
      exports: 'jQuery'
    }
  },

  optimize: 'uglify2',
  uglify2: {
    warnings: false,
    /* Mangling defeats Angular injection by function argument names. */
    mangle: false
  }
})

define(['jquery', 'angular'], function($, angular) {
  /* Angular bootstrap. */
})
```

Comment: Looks great, Michael, thanks for sharing. I will try it today.

Comment: Well, it really works (the only change I made is adding shim targeting main.js in build.scala -- due to coffeescript processing). So now I don't need to support shim.coffee, and waitSeconds:0 doesn't affect app since all dependencies are local. Thanks!